# Getting json as a pojo

Tags: java, json, jersey, pojo

This is my object

```
public class ServiceGroup {

    private String ParticipantIdentifierScheme;
    private String ParticipantIdentifierValue;

    public void setParticipantIdentifierScheme(String ParticipantIdentifierScheme) {
        this.ParticipantIdentifierScheme = ParticipantIdentifierScheme;
    }

    public String getParticipantIdentifierScheme() {
        return ParticipantIdentifierScheme;
    }

    public void setParticipantIdentifierValue(String ParticipantIdentifierValue) {
        this.ParticipantIdentifierValue = ParticipantIdentifierValue;
    }

    public String getParticipantIdentifierValue() {
        return ParticipantIdentifierValue;
    }
```

The request is handled that way

```
@Path("/participants")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addUserToSMP(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString, ServiceGroup sg) {
    return Response.ok().entity(sg).build();
}
```

And i have put that little Response in order to see what exactly is parsed.

My input should be like this

```
{
  "ParticipantIdentifierScheme": "scheme",
  "ParticipantIdentifierValue": "value"
}
```

But the output is the following

```
{
  "participantIdentifierScheme": null,
  "participantIdentifierValue": null
}
```

What i really want, is to somehow check the input if it's in correct format, and keep them in the ServiceGroup object for further use

**UPDATE**

Setting the variables as public returns the following

```
{
  "ParticipantIdentifierScheme": "scheme",
  "participantIdentifierScheme": "scheme",
  "ParticipantIdentifierValue": "value",
  "participantIdentifierValue": "value",
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ServiceGroup {

    @XmlElement(name = "ParticipantIdentifierScheme")
    private String ParticipantIdentifierScheme;

    @XmlElement(name = "ParticipantIdentifierValue")
    private String ParticipantIdentifierValue;
```

and i get

```
{
  "ParticipantIdentifierScheme": "scheme",
  "participantIdentifierScheme": "scheme",
  "ParticipantIdentifierValue": "value",
  "participantIdentifierValue": "value"
}
```

Comment: Annotate somehow `ServiceGroup sg` (probably `@RequestBody`).
Add annotation `@XmlRootElement` for class `ServiceGroup` and for fields `@XmlElement(name = "ParticipantIdentifierScheme")`.

Comment: @glw please check my update

Comment: Just for test change `ParticipantIdentifierScheme` to `participantIdentifierScheme`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the serialization will also look at your getter methods. You should only annotate the getter method as the element. It is seeing the 4 different values because you have the uppercase variable name as your private variables and the getters will be seen as lower case. You can also use the @XmlAccessorType to specify that you only want to serialize public members.

See here

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Change your variables to lowercase and only annotate your getter method. Don't annotate the setter methods. It will complain as it is redundant.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ServiceGroup {

    private String participantIdentifierScheme;
    private String participantIdentifierValue;

    public void setParticipantIdentifierScheme(String ParticipantIdentifierScheme) {
        this.ParticipantIdentifierScheme = ParticipantIdentifierScheme;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ParticipantIdentifierScheme")
    public String getParticipantIdentifierScheme() {
        return ParticipantIdentifierScheme;
    }

    public void setParticipantIdentifierValue(String ParticipantIdentifierValue) {
        this.ParticipantIdentifierValue = ParticipantIdentifierValue;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="ParticipantIdentifierValue")
    public String getParticipantIdentifierValue() {
        return ParticipantIdentifierValue;
    }
```